# Unrecognized option 'sync'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: ffmpeg, synchronization, adb

I am following this tutorial to [project Android screen to PC via ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154328/94084).

```
.\adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffmpeg ffplay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video
```

The error is:

```
Unrecognized option 'sync'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I've searched for similar errors about unrecognized option, but I still don't know how to solve it.

If I remove the `-sync video` argument then the error is:

```
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
[NULL @ 000001f0d0678b00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffplay'
ffplay: Invalid argument
```

The ffmpeg version is 4.2.3, but I don't think this matters.

Answer (score 0):

ffplay is a separate tool. So, it should be

```
... | ffplay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video -f h264 -
```